# How to tell what javascript code is causing a visible change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

jQuery/javascript/css

Specifically, I'm working on some code that triggers changes when certain divs hits the window top.

I have 3 divs set that way. And the first two act as expected.

But for some reason, the 3rd div causes the window to instantly jump back up to wherever it was when I began my last scrolling action. i.e. I click the scroll bar and start dragging down, and when I hit the div, boom, the window is back to where it was when I clicked.

Is there any way I can track the code to get exactly what events are being executed? Is there an easier way than sprinkling `console.log()` all over my code and praying?

I wish I could step through the code at that point to see each change in state including DOM.

Comment: It seems like you have duplicate div id's at first. I could be wrong but request you to check.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but no, these divs don't have ids. Here is the fiddle if you are interested in digging deeper: http://jsfiddle.net/nvSdQ/1/

Comment: If I understand correctly (and I'm not sure that I do understand) -- I __do not__ experience the problem you describe, when running your jsFiddle using Firefox.  IOW as I move the scrollbar downwards in the browser, your three divs sequentially arrive the top, and then stay pinned there, one beneath the next.  No jumping occurs.

Comment: @ButtleButkus what DavidTansey just explained happens with me as well - everything works if it was expected.

Comment: @ButtleButkus I **do** experience the problem in Chrome 28. No solution though, sorry.

Comment: @JasonP, I'm not seeing it on `28.0.1500.89 beta`, Linux.

Comment: Thanks for trying that out guys. The jumping problem seems to only occur when the window width is smaller than a certain size. But I'm not seeing it in the fiddle. Using chrome 28.0.1500.95 m, I am getting it at window width 735px, for example, but not at 945px. A 2nd problem that I DO see in the fiddle is if you scroll down the page and then change the window width repeatedly, the stuck divs end up with spaces between them. Somehow, the code for setting the `top` value must be returning the wrong code. Does that have to do with javascript code not waiting for return values??

Comment: @ButtleButkus That's right, the problem with the jump does not occur if the window is wider than the three divs, that is, if it does not have a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @MrLister I did not notice that correlation. That is an important clue that could help, though I'm not sure what to do with it yet. Thanks a lot for your helpfulness.